# How to merge and work zencoderfetcher with Video in Drupal 7

Tags: video, drupal-7, zencoder

Module Installed : Video, Video.js, Zencoder API

Versions Installed :-

Zencoder library -2.1.2, Video.js--3.2.0, Video transcoder: Zencoder--1.2

I successfully get the Zencoder API key after creating account in Zencoder. Postback URL was shown as localhost/VideoSample/postback/jobs.

I uploaded mp4 video in Video content type and got the following error:

"Something went wrong with transcoding big_buck_bunny.mp4. Please check your recent log entries for further debugging."

When I visit recent log entries I found the following error:-

- The notification url (localhost/VideoSample/postback/jobs) has
  an invalid host: localhost/VideoSample/postback/jobs
- r10k is not a supported video codec. Options include h264, mpeg4,
  theora, vp6, vp8, and wmv.

After a bit of study in Internet I found that Zencoder need some public hosted IP or public server for sending the transcode video. In my case the site is not public as I am working on localhost. Basically after a research I found two options for getting the ob done.

- Download Amazon s3 module and create a bucket in there. Provide the
  address of Amazon to Zencoder API. But this requires a cost for
  hosting videos in Amazon. I drop this option for my experiment

Zencoder provides a tool called Zencoder Fetcher to transcode the video free of cost. It needs Ruby and Ruby Gems to installed on windows 7. I downloaded Ruby and RubyuGems and  follow this resource for installing material.

http://blog.zencoder.com/2011/08/25/fetcher-making-it-even-easier-to-integrate-with-zencoder/

When I give my API key then I got following message.Notification retrieved :0.

I gave the url "zencoderfetcher" as mentioned inside "Postback URL for Zencoder" in admin/config/media/video/transcoders. But I get following message after saving the option.

"The postback URL cannot be retrieved: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (0)."

Then I provide the url "localhost/zencoder/notifications_handler" in the same place and I get the message again as follows:-

"The postback URL cannot be retrieved: missing schema (-1002)."

I need transcoding badly in my project. Please let me know if it is possible to merge and work zencoderfetcher with video module. If yes then it would be very kind if you provide any reference or steps for this.

Note:- All url has http as prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered this in the Drupal forums, but I'll answer here as well in case anyone else finds this.

Essentially all Fetcher does is query the notifications API to get the most recent notifications, and then POSTS those to localhost:3000 (or whatever you set as the local address). This only applies to the notification, and the video must still be uploaded somewhere, so I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say, "Zencoder provides a tool called Zencoder Fetcher to transcode the video free of cost."

It sounds like what's happening here is the module is trying to validate the address, so zencoderfetcher as the notification url won't work. There are other projects that do similar things, such as localtunnel that might solve the issue. With localtunnel you get a valid URI to post your notifications to, but it also requires Ruby / RubyGems.